# Is it possible to set expiration date for Webpush subscription?

Tags: javascript, authentication, service-worker, web-push

I've read quite a lot of documentation about Webpush, and so far I've understood that push subscription should have a **read-only** propery `expirationTime`. Also, I understand how should I react if the **browser** decides that subscription is outdated (handle event in service worker, etc.). But is it possible to somehow set expiration date manually, without implementing complex client side logic? I guess that this is an ordinary problem for apps that have authentification.

My problem is that if user gets logged out automatically, webpush endpoint stays valid. I know multiple ways this can be solved with workarounds, but I guess that's not the optimal way for a relatively basic problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time ago that I've fixed this, but I guess sharing my solution can be helpful.

The solution was to make a HTTP request from service worker to the app using `fetch('/path')` , because all cookies from the app are also attached to requests made from SW.

So, if user is not logged in, you are redirected to login page.

My code:

```
    fetch('/path', {method: 'GET', redirect:'error'}).then(function(result) {
         ... //some code specific for my app
    }).catch(function(e) {
        registration.unregister(); //error on redirect to login
    });
```

Comment: How does this set the expiration date?

Comment: It doesn't set expiration date, but it solves the problem using different approach: we no longer need SW when user is logged out, so we check directly from SW if user is logged in by sending an HTTP and checking does it get a response (user logged in), or redirection (user not logged in).

Comment: Note that in case of unreliable network conditions, you may get an error from `fetch` and that would kill the push subscription without reason. Basically your idea is interesting, but there's a risk to lose valid subscribers!